# Backing up gmail, alternatives to thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

Since mozilla thunderbird is not continuing to be developed, what other options are there to backup gmail?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine any other imap client for linux.

Also, thunderbird isn't useless overnight just because development stops.

Comment: it is, however worse than useless because of the bugs that have been introduced that make it unusable.

Comment: like ? Works just fine for me.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=942610  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/513399 http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2798423 http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=2037665

Comment: weird. most of those bugs are dated during time that i've used thunderbird every single day. Never had any of those issues.

Comment: Then you are blessed, because it happens to me constantly. Every time I try and send an email I am thwarted by the changing focus problem. This is compounded by the undo problem, where since I've accidentally deleted messages, I hit ctrl-z to undo the action, and it manages to undelete a much older deleted message, not the one I just deleted. These are all things that used to work that have been broken recently.

Comment: which distro are you using ? Maybe mine is too old.

Comment: xubuntu 14.04. Yeah, thunderbird used to work fine, then they kept touching it and making it worse. I'm sure if I go back and do a build from a few years ago it would work, but then you lose all the security updates.